# Winforms window freezes

Tags: c#, winforms, freeze

Winforms C#

I'm implementing a power up system in my snake game and every time i run the method to spawn a power up the window completely stops as if it was processing something heavy but forever. i don't get any error nor windows asking to close window.

this is my script:

```
        private void spawn_powerup()
    {
        int r = random.Next(0, Powers.Length);
        foreach (Power_Up item in Powers)
        {
            if (item.code == r)
            {
                bool done = false;
                do
                {
                    int X = random.Next(0, grid_size);
                    int Y = random.Next(0, grid_size);
                    if (matriz[X, Y] == background_color)
                    {
                        matriz[X, Y] = item.Pixel_color;
                        done = true;
                        item.placed = true;
                    }
                } while (done);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are never setting `done` to `false` inside the loop

Comment: `while(done)` is most likely the cause of the freeze.

Comment: @UnholySheep why would i? its suppose to leave (whenmatriz[X, Y] == background_color)

Comment: You can also substitute `done = true;` with `break;`, use `while (true);` and get rid of `bool done = false;`. This if the condition `if (matriz[X, Y] == background_color)` is met at some point.

Comment: You are also using `Random` incorrectly.

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

You never set `done` to `false` inside your `do-while-loop`.

So if within your first iteration your if expression evaluates to `true`, `done` is set to `true` and your `do-while` runs forever

For what I think you want to achieve change your `do-while` condition to `!done`, but then you have to make sure that your `if` condition is met after some time (but in a snake game this shouldn't be much of an issue).

Answer (score 0):

First of all your while logic is wrong. While loop continues when it is set to `true`, and exits whenever it gets `false` or `break;` command is issued.

Also you are using Synchronous programming pattern. So your application runs on single thread and whenever you call long running function you application start to wait that long running function to finish. Then it resumes continuing.

Please consider to look [Asynchronous Programming in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)
Another [Reference](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/asynchronous-programming-in-C-Sharp-5-0-part-1-understand-async/)

Answer (score 0):

Your loop conditions will never allow it to stop, since you wrote `while(done)`, which means: "while done is set to true", which it always is.
You should change you loop to this:

```
bool done = false;
do
{
    (- your code here -)
} while (!done);
```